# Converting string array into a string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm working on a cipher program that uses a columnar transposition cipher. I start by grabbing the user input and putting it into a string array, then printing a shuffled version of the array. To decipher the message, I'm unshuffling the encrypted message and attempting to print the message one element from each "column" in the string array.

For example, if my message is "Hey there dude", it will be encrypted to "TD* HU* ERE __* YE* HED" (spaces are replaced by underscores, and null spaces are replaced by asterisks). The decryption should then reorganize the array, then go through the first item in each element of the array, print it to a string, and then move on to the second item in each element of the array to print it to a string, and so forth.

```
        string[] columnEncrypted = userMessage.Split(' ');
        string[] columnDecrypted = new string[6];
        string DecryptedString = string.Empty;

        columnDecrypted[0] = columnEncrypted[5];
        columnDecrypted[1] = columnEncrypted[2];
        columnDecrypted[2] = columnEncrypted[4];
        columnDecrypted[3] = columnEncrypted[3];
        columnDecrypted[4] = columnEncrypted[0];
        columnDecrypted[5] = columnEncrypted[1];

        for (int r = 0; r <= columnDecrypted.Length; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++)
            {
                if (columnDecrypted[c] == "_")
                {
                    DecryptedString += ' ';
                }
                else
                {
                    DecryptedString += columnDecrypted[c];
                }
            }
        }
        return DecryptedString;
```

This is my first time posting a question here, so please bear with me if my explanation is unclear. If more code is needed to better answer my question, please let me know and I will provide more.

The encryption code is as follows:

```
public string CipheredString(string userMessage)
    {
        string[] column = new string[6];

        for(int c = 0; c <= 5; c++)
        {
            for (int i = c; i < userMessage.Length; i += 6)
            {
                if (userMessage[i] == '.')
                {
                    column[c] += "."; 
                }
                else if (userMessage[i] == ',')
                {
                    column[c] += ",";
                }
                else if (userMessage[i] == '?')
                {
                    column[c] += "?";
                }
                else if (userMessage[i] == '!')
                {
                    column[c] += "!";
                }
                else if (userMessage[i] == ' ')
                {
                    column[c] += "_";
                }
                else
                {
                    column[c] += userMessage[i];
                }
            }
        }

        if (column[5].Length < column[0].Length)
        {
            if (column[4].Length < column[0].Length)
            {
                if (column[3].Length < column[0].Length)
                {
                    if (column[2].Length < column[0].Length)
                    {
                        if (column[1].Length < column[0].Length)
                        {
                            column[1] += "*";
                            column[2] += "*";
                            column[3] += "*";
                            column[4] += "*";
                            column[5] += "*";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            column[2] += "*";
                            column[3] += "*";
                            column[4] += "*";
                            column[5] += "*";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        column[3] += "*";
                        column[4] += "*";
                        column[5] += "*";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    column[4] += "*";
                    column[5] += "*";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                column[5] += "*";
            }
        }

        string EncryptedString = column[4] + " " + column[5] + " " + column[1] + " " + column[3] + " " + column[2] + " " + column[0];
        return EncryptedString;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm... what is the question?

Comment: You did a nice job of describing what your program is supposed to do, but I think you forgot to explain your problem. :)

Comment: For us to answer your question, you would need to tell us your question.

Comment: I need to get the decrypted string to print "Hey_there_dude****". right now it's printing something more along the lines of "HEDEREYE*__*TD*HU*HEDEREYE*__*TD*HU*HEDEREYE*__*TD*HU*HEDEREYE*__*TD*HU*"

Comment: Place the code for encrypting it

Comment: VS comes with a powerful debugger.  Use it and learn.

Comment: I have and I understand why it's printing like that. I'm trying to find out how to pull just one item out of each element before moving on to the next element, and upon reaching the last element, start back at the first element, but the second item. I.e. column[0] = "HED". I just want "H" before moving on to column[1].

Comment: Did you mean you want to get substring from the string? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up solving my issue:

```
public string CipheredString(string userMessage)
    {
        string[] columnEncrypted = userMessage.Split(' ');
        string[] columnDecrypted = new string[6];
        string DecryptedString = string.Empty;
        string DirtyDecrypt = string.Empty;

        columnDecrypted[0] = columnEncrypted[5];
        columnDecrypted[1] = columnEncrypted[2];
        columnDecrypted[2] = columnEncrypted[4];
        columnDecrypted[3] = columnEncrypted[3];
        columnDecrypted[4] = columnEncrypted[0];
        columnDecrypted[5] = columnEncrypted[1];

        for (int c = 0; c < columnDecrypted[0].Length; c++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++)
            {
                string row = columnDecrypted[r];
                string column = row[c].ToString();
                DirtyDecrypt += column;
            }
        }
        string CleanDecrypt = DirtyDecrypt.Replace("_", " ").Replace("*","");

        return CleanDecrypt;
    }
```